# Exclude characters for SCP-filepattern

Tags: wildcards, scp

Is there a way to build an expression for `scp` with which I can manage to copy the file

```
file-name-version-1.2.1.jar
```

without copying the files

```
file-name-version-1.2.1-sources.jar
file-name-version-1.2.1-javadoc.jar
```

while not knowing the exact version numbers? `file-name-version-*.*.*.jar` won't work for obvious reasons. I'm looking for a syntax like

```
file-name-version-\d.\d.\d.jar
```

or something similar.

Comment: If the version could contain digits, `ls file-name-version-*|tail -1` will get you that file name, since `ls` sorts alphabetically and `.` comes after `-`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to bear in mind is that the filename is passed *unmodified* to the login shell of the remote user.

If you do:

```
 scp user@remote-machine:'something' ...
```

On the remote machine, `sshd` will run the login shell of `user` as:

```
 that-shell -c 'scp -f something'
```

And it's that shell that will expand the patterns in there.

What that means is that the way the pattern is expanded will depend on what login shell the remote user is using. When that shell is `bash`, that will also depend on what the user has in his `~/.bashrc`, or what there is in `/etc/bash.bashrc` (for instance `bash-completion` called from there when installed turns on ksh-style extended globbing) since for some reason `bash` reads those when called over `ssh` (even though that's not an interactive shell).

What that also means is that if `something` is for instance `'blah; rm -rf "$HOME"'`, that will have catastrophic consequences.

That's one of the misdesigns of `ssh`.

If you want to force a specific shell to expand that `something` into a list of files, you can use this trick:

```
LC_SCPFILES=something scp -o SendEnv=LC_SCPFILES "localhost:</dev/null
  bash -O extglob -c 'exec scp -f -- \$LC_SCPFILES';exit" /dest/dir
```

That only works if the login shell of the remote user is a normal Unix shell (of the Bourne, csh, rc or fish families at least), and `bash` is installed over there and `sshd` allows passing environment variables whose name starts with `LC_`.

The trick is that most `sshd` deployments allow passing environment variables whose name starts with `LC_` (needed so that a Spanish user can get error messages from the remote commands in Spanish (instead of the default language on the remote system or the language of the remote user) for instance).

So here, we pass `something` in a `LC_SCPFILES` environment variable.

On the remote machine, `sshd` will run:

```
that-shell -c 'scp -f </dev/null
  bash -O extglob -c '\''exec scp -f -- $LC_SCPFILES'\'';exit'
```

Because its stdin is redirected from `/dev/null`, the first `scp` will exit straight away. Then we start our shell of choice (`bash`), with the `extglob` option, and with the `exec scp -f -- $LC_SCPFILES` command line to interpret.

Because `bash` will run in a child process of `that-shell` (which we enforce by adding a `;exit` afterwards), `bash` will not source the `~/.bashrc`, so we can expect the default behaviour of `bash` there (unless somehow `that-shell`, on startup, sets the `BASHOPTS`, `SHELLOPTS` or `BASH_ENV` environment variables).

Because `$LC_SCPFILES` is not quoted, it will be subject to word splitting and filename generation (globbing), but not the other shells expansions, and it will not do things likes `rm -rf "$HOME"` just because `something` contains it.

Now that we made sure that the pattern is expanded by `bash -O extglob` on the remote machine, we can use it to match a pattern that uses extended glob operators (here using a helper function):

```
safer_scp() (
  file=$1; shift
  export LC_SCPFILES="${file#*:}"
  exec scp -o SendEnv=LC_SCPFILES "${file%%:*}:</dev/null
    bash -O extglob -c 'exec scp -f -- \$LC_SCPFILES';exit" "$@"
)
safer_scp user@host:'file-name-version-+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9]).jar' .
```

The `+([0-9])`, with `extglob` on in `bash` matches one or more decimal digits. So the pattern above would match `file-name-version-1.2.3.jar` and `file-name-version-12.123.1234.jar` for instance.

(note that the `safer_scp` above assumes the first argument is the `host:file-patterns`, things like `safer_scp -r ...` or `safer_scp host1:f1 host2:f2 ...` won't work. If you want to use `-r`, the easiest is to define a `safer_scp_r` function where `scp -f` above is replaced with `scp -r -f`).

Note that you can disable word splitting by adding a `IFS=;` before the `exec scp...` above.

Also note that we're using `bash` here on the basis that it's installed on all GNU systems, but if you know `zsh` is installed on the remote system, you can use

```
zsh -o extendedglob -o globsust
```

instead to benefit from the full power of `zsh` globbing (recursive, qualifiers...)

(add `-o shwordsplit` if you want word splitting as well).

For example:

```
safer_scp() (
  file=$1; shift
  export LC_SCPFILES="${file#*:}"
  exec scp -o SendEnv=LC_SCPFILES "${file%%:*}:</dev/null
    zsh -o extendedglob -o globsubst -c 'exec scp -f -- \$LC_SCPFILES';exit" "$@"
)
safer_scp user@host:'file-name-version-<->(.<->)#.jar' .
```

Would copy `file-name-version-1.jar` and `file-name-version-1.2.3.4.5.jar` (`<x-y>` is any decimal integer number from `x` to `y`, `<->` is any decimal integer number, `#` is like the `*` regexp operator (0 or more of the preceding atom))

Comment: Holy cow, that is an awesome answer!

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case

```
scp 'user@host:file-name-version-*[0-9].jar' .
```

might be enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
file-name-version-[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].jar
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Note that it won't work for 1.10.2.

Answer (score 1):

For flexibility, use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) instead of scp.

```
rsync --include='file-name-*.jar' \
      --exclude='*-sources.jar' --exclude='*-javadoc.jar' \
      example.com:/some/directory/ local/directory/
```